# How to update column in sql by similar data in another table

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Hello guys example of data in the two tabels:

I have table MSISDNs_for_Import with two columns:

```
msisdn          sim
359898855753    99085719352
```

And my another table is SIMs_for_Import  with these two columns:

```
IMSI                      SIMNO
284010160719352           8935901990857193529
```

My question is how can i make to update my first table column sim with the value of the second table column simno

I am trying with this query:

```
UPDATE MSISDNs_for_Import
SET MSISDNs_for_Import.sim=
  (SELECT SIMs_for_Import.SIMNO
   FROM SIMs_for_Import
   WHERE MSISDNs_for_Import.sim=SIMs_for_Import.SIMNO )
```

but it save nulls in MSISDNs_for_Import.sim column

Comment: you need to update "sim" field with "SIMNO" field in another table, so you need to join and update. For joining the two tables you need a common field

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any relationship between the two tables that would allow you to determine which value `SIMNO` in `SIMs_for_Import` should replace which value of `sim` in `MSISDNs_for_Import`

Comment: What's the number similar between the two tables?

Comment: similar is this 99085719352 becouse i need the last digit to add of the second column 893590199085719352 9  <-- and to cut all these symbols  8935901 and the data of the sim column to be 990857193529 not 99085719352

Answer (score 0):

I think maybe you're looking for something like this.

```
UPDATE ms
SET 
    ms.sim= si.SIMNO
FROM 
    MSISDNs_for_Import ms
INNER JOIN SIMs_for_Import si
    ON ms.sim = LEFT(RIGHT(si.SIMNO, LENGTH(ms.sim) + 1), LENGTH(ms.sim))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
UPDATE MSISDNs_for_Import a
        JOIN
    SIMs_for_Import b 
SET 
    a.sim = SUBSTRING(b.SIMNO, 8, 12)
WHERE
    a.sim = SUBSTRING(b.SIMNO, 8, 11);
```